# json response from the server (how to populate the response from server in selectbox)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate a select box (cities related to a state) using the $.ajax method of jquery.

I wrote the following in my php script

```
    $('#cmbState').change(function(){
  $('#cmbCity').children().remove();
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../include/ajax.php",
   data: "option=getCitiesList&stateid="+$(this).val()+"",
   dataType: "json",
   complete: function(response){
     'what should I write in here ..?'
     },
   beforeSend: function(){$('#cmbCity').addClass('show_loading_in_center')},
   success: function(){$('#cmbCity').removeClass('show_loading_in_center')}
     });
    });
```

and in the file 'ajax.php' (file where the query is sent for getting the realted cities) I did

```
$i=0;
foreach($cities as $city)
 {
  $response[$i]['id'] = $city['pk_cityid'];
  $response[$i]['name'] = $city['name'];
  $i++;
 }
 echo json_encode($response);
```

Now the response comes as XMLHTTPResponse object.
How shall I populate the response into cities selectbox.?

Please help, I am really stuck over here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#cmbState').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../include/ajax.php",
        data: {option: "getCitiesList", stateid: $(this).val()},
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {
            var $cmbCity = $('#cmbCity').empty();
            $.each(data, function () {
                 $cmbCity.append('<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.name + '</option>')
            });
        },

        beforeSend: function(){ $('#cmbCity').addClass('show_loading_in_center') },
        complete: function(){ $('#cmbCity').removeClass('show_loading_in_center') }
    });
});
```

You need to write a `success` handler that will be called with the data passed (`completed` is called even on error). The data is passed as the first argument. We first `empty()` the select and assign it to `$cmbCity` for performance reasons. Then we iterate over `data` using `$.each` (cross-browser jQuery iteration) that binds each of the elements to `this`. Using that we create new options in the `#cmbCity` select.

The above code assumes that the response is in the following format:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "London"}, 
 {"id": 2, "name": "Paris"},
 {"id": 3, "name": "New York"}]
```

Also, note that `data` (in the $.ajax call above) is in key-value format - jQuery will serialize it automatically.

Comment: :)
great that worked like a charm..
thanks man. You saved me.. :-)